# Why XOR of all subsets of a list have same frequency?

Tags: math, subset, xor, bitwise-xor

I have a list of numbers `a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, ...` and so on. If we find `XOR` of all subsets then I noticed that frequency of each distinct `XOR` is the same.

**Example 1**

```
# list of numbers    
[2, 0, 9]

# XOR of all subsets including empty set
XOR of () = 0
XOR of (2,) = 2
XOR of (0,) = 0
XOR of (9,) = 9
XOR of (2, 0) = 2
XOR of (2, 9) = 11
XOR of (0, 9) = 9
XOR of (2, 0, 9) = 11

# Frequency of each XOR value
{0: 2, 2: 2, 9: 2, 11: 2}
```

In the above example, we can see that `XOR` values `0, 2, 9, 11` have the same frequency that is `2`

**Example 2**

It doesn't matter what is the size of the list, whether elements are repeated or not, the property seems to hold

```
# list of numbers
[2, 0, 9, 9, 9, 45, 1, 2, 1, 1]

# skipping showing the subsets

# Frequency of each XOR value
{0: 64,
 2: 64,
 9: 64,
 45: 64,
 1: 64,
 11: 64,
 47: 64,
 3: 64,
 36: 64,
 8: 64,
 44: 64,
 38: 64,
 10: 64,
 46: 64,
 37: 64,
 39: 64}
```

First of all, I am not sure whether it will always hold. I have tested it for quite a few numbers of examples and it seems to work for all of them. There are a lot of `XOR` questions asked on StackOverflow but I didn't find anything related to this question.

Can someone please help with the following?

- Whether this property will always hold?
- If no, can you share 1 example?
- If yes, can you please answer why?

Comment: The details are probably too mathematical for stackoverflow, but the short summary is XOR can be viewed as a linear operation over an n-dimensional vector space, where n is *at most* the number of bits in the largest number in your original set, when viewing the numbers as vectors of bits. Some subset of the numbers in your original set are a basis for the vector space spanned by the set. That basis will generate the entire vector space spanned by it, its size is a power of 2.  Once you have this basis the other numbers in the set contribute nothing, removing them changes nothing.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I am aware that using the linear combination of basis elements we can generate all possible values of XOR but my question to you is how can we use this information to prove that frequency of all XOR values will be same

Comment: If  list size is n and its basis size is m then the frequency of each xor value will be pow(2, n-m) provided the same frequency property holds

Comment: Yes, I understand I did answer a slightly different question than the one you asked. I was hoping you could take my comment and come up with the answer yourself :)

Comment: It is somewhat tedious, but you can prove this by induction. The chief observation is that when you extend your original set S to S' by an additional element a_k, the number of subsets doubles, and is equal to all the all the subsets of S plus all the subsets of S with a_k appended. Now there are two cases: either a_k is linearly independent of the vectors of S or not. In the first case the number of outputs doubles and each output has the same number of preimages, and the second case the number of outputs stays the same and each output has twice as many preimages.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know about the linear combination of basis elements.,

Let **a<sub>i1</sub>,a<sub>i2</sub>,a<sub>i3</sub>,....a<sub>ik</sub>** be the basis elements for the given array.

We get 2<sup>k</sup> unique xor values by spanning above set.

- Let that set be **X = **{ x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>,.......x<sub>2<sup>k</sup></sub> }****

Now coming to remaining (n-k) non basis elements,
There are 2<sup>(n-k)</sup> subsets among them.

- let the set of xor of each subsets be **D = { d<sub>1</sub>,d<sub>2</sub>,....d<sub>2<sup>n-k</sup></sub> }**

> **Note: ∀di∈X**
> **proof:**
> We know that, Each di is xor of(linear combination of) some subset of non basis elements, and a non basis elements itself linearly representable using basis elements.
> (ie:can be formed by xor-ing some subset of basis elements).
>
> Therefore, each di is linearly representable with basis element, thus it belongs to set X.

Now coming to the original question, let A be given array.

Then set of subset of **A = X×D**.

> Because X is set of subset of some k distinct element of array, and D is set of subset of remaining n-k elements., So merging them with all combinations gives set of subset of original array

**Claim:** **∀i, Li=di⊕X** produces the same set, actually the **set X** itself, but just in different order.

> **proof:**
> For any two **different** integer p,q : we have **p⊕u≠q⊕u**
>
> Since all x1,x2...... are distinct.
> Here di is similar to u in above equation.
> so **Li = di⊕X = ​di⊕{x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>,......}** produces a another unique set of numbers.
>
> ie: li<sub>j</sub> ≠ li<sub>k</sub> for j≠k 
> Now we are left with proving that each Li is X itself.
>
> > **proof:**
> >
> > The value of Each li<sub>j</sub>∈Li cannot have any new value apart that span of basis, as li<sub>j</sub> = di⊕x<sub>j</sub>, here what we did is only linear combination within basis.
> >
> > So all li<sub>j</sub> still belongs to span of basis(and distinct). so, the Li is X.

---

Now the size of D is 2^(n-k), and ∀i, di×X = X

hence the same set of xor values in X is repeated 2^(n-k) times.

ie: each element in X (span of basis elements) is repeated 2^(n-k) times.
Where k is number of basis elements.